# Spinner in Kotlin Jetpack Navigation Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I cannot get the spinner to work normally in my fragment. The error I'm getting is "ArrayAdapter function cannot be called" on the ArrayAdapter line.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
    val list : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    for (i in 1..1000)
        list.add("Item $i")
    val adapter :ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list)
    spinnerCompany.adapter = adapter
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `this` with `requireContext()`

```
 val adapter : ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list)
```